Publish nodejs package with binary files built from git project
I have a git project, which itself includes git submodules. I want to build those projects and publish the resulting node binding.
Here are the steps needed:

Clone project and all submodules recursively
Run cmake build (can be done via cmake-js)
Pack resulting binary binding into node package
Pack some js files into the package

Here are my questions:

Should I build my binary for all architectures before publishing the package?
If building the package only when installing, do I need to include all source files in the package?
If building when installing, can I somehow clone a repository on the installing machine?

Thanks!
